# Associate many QButtons with many QLineEdits

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

The app I am building looks like this:[image]

The app will include several more QToolButtons and QLineEdits. When a QToolbutton is pressed always a color dialog is presented. The hex code of the color is added to the LineEdit. Is it possible that each QLineEdit is associated to a QToolButton so that when a button is pressed the app automatically knows what LineEdit to add the text to. Currently the code I am using is:

```
self.connect(self.bgbut, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.bgbut_click) #bgbut is the QToolButton
```

And then calling

```
def bgbut_click(self):
```

But this will become impractical for the fifteen plus line edits and ToolButtons i will add. So is there any way to efficiently associate each toolbutton to the corresponding LineEdit?

Comment: What do you mean by "app automatically knows what LineEdit to add the text to". Where does the text come from? Is it always a color dialog or always something else?

Comment: Always from the color dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to do the following three steps.

Step 1: While or after setup of the UI of the widget create a dictionary with all buttons as keys and all line edits as values.

```
self.button_map = {}
self.button_map[self.but1] = self.edit1
self.button_map[self.but2] = self.edit2
..
```

Step 2: Connect all buttons to the same method in the widget. You already did that, I guess.

```
self.but1.clicked.connect(self.buttons_clicked)
self.but2.clicked.connect(self.buttons_clicked)
..
```

Step 3: In the method that is connected to all buttons get the `sender`, look up the corresponding line edit from the dictionary created before and set the text accordingly.

```
def buttons_clicked(self):
  text = color_dialog_get_some_text() # customize this
  self.button_map[self.sender].setText(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have two widgets that are interacting in some way, it is often simpler to create a custom widget to handle everything for you. I've written a custom `QColorWidget` [here](http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/qcolorbutton-a-color-selector-tool-for-pyqt/) that presents a button that once pressed shows a color dialog. Selecting a color changes the color of the button, but it is simple to display it as a hex color in a `QLineEdit` instead. The original code is:

```
class QColorButton(QPushButton):
    '''
    Custom Qt Widget to show a chosen color.

    Left-clicking the button shows the color-chooser, while
    right-clicking resets the color to None (no-color).    
    '''

    colorChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QColorButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._color = None
        self.setMaximumWidth(32)
        self.pressed.connect(self.onColorPicker)

    def setColor(self, color):
        if color != self._color:
            self._color = color
            self.colorChanged.emit()

        if self._color:
            self.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % self._color)
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet("")

    def color(self):
        return self._color

    def onColorPicker(self):
        '''
        Show color-picker dialog to select color.

        Qt will use the native dialog by default.

        '''
        dlg = QColorDialog(self)
        if self._color:
            dlg.setCurrentColor(QColor(self._color))

        if dlg.exec_():
            self.setColor(dlg.currentColor().name())

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.setColor(None)

        return super(QColorButton, self).mousePressEvent(e)
```

We can modify this to show a `QLineEdit` adjacent as follows. Rather than inheriting directly from the `QPushButton` we inherit from the generic `QWidget`. To that we set a layout containing a `QLabel` and a `QPushButton`. Instead of storing the color internally (as `_color`) we now set and retrieve it from the `QLabel` via `QLabel.text()` and `QLabel.setText()`.

```
class QColorLineEditButton(QWidget):
    '''
    Custom Qt Widget to show a chosen color alongside a QLineEdit.

    Left-clicking the button shows the color-chooser, while
    right-clicking resets the color to None (no-color).    
    '''

    colorChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QColorLineEditButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.le.setMaximumWidth(100)

        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setMaximumWidth(32)

        layout.addWidget(self.le)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.btn.pressed.connect(self.onColorPicker)

    def setColor(self, color):
        if color != self.le.text():
            self.le.setText(color)
            self.colorChanged.emit()

        if self.le.text():
            self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % self.le.text())
        else:
            self.btn.setStyleSheet("")

    def color(self):
        return self.le.text()

    def onColorPicker(self):
        '''
        Show color-picker dialog to select color.

        Qt will use the native dialog by default.

        '''
        dlg = QColorDialog(self)
        if self.le.text():
            dlg.setCurrentColor(QColor(self.le.text()))

        if dlg.exec_():
            self.setColor(dlg.currentColor().name())
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Screenshot of QColorLineEditButton]

You can add this to your form as normal by e.g.

```
color1 = QColorLineEditButton()
layout.addWidget(color1)
```

Then read values out using the color() access function.

```
current_color_1 = color1.color()
```

However, if you're going to be handling a lot of widgets on a form may this will get very cumbersome. In that case may I make a small plug for my PyQt config-manager module [PyQtConfig](http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/pyqtconfig-a-simple-api-for-keeping-your-pyqt-widgets-and-config-in-sync/) which allows you access (set, and get) multiple widgets through a standard Python dict interface.